# Where can I change Intel OpenGL settings on Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl

Earlier versions of Intel's graphics control panel included a dedicated section for OpenGL, where one could change, i.e. the buffer flip method.  With the most recent drivers, I can no longer find a dedicated OpenGL settings page, and the 3D settings page only includes texture quality, AF, vertex processing and vsync.  How can I change the more advanced settings?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you dealing with? And which Intel graphics?

Comment: Windows 7 32-bit, Intel 4500 HD, Driver version 8.15.10.2361.